# May a woman be a kvater?

Tags: halacha, minhag, women, brit-milah

May a woman serve as the sole kvater (person who brings the baby to the sandek) at a bris? At most britot I've been to, the duty of kvater was handled by a woman and a man (typically married), with the woman bringing the baby from the mother to the man, and the man bringing the baby to the sandek, I'm asking if a woman (or women) only can serve that role.

[possibly related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13568/baby-boys-mother-as-the-sandeket)

Comment: "kvaterin", I believe, is the feminine.

Comment: Can men alone serve?

Comment: I was just at a double bris for a friend of mine. there were several people who passed each of the newborns and the passing has started with the two grandmothers

Answer (score 4):

**A woman can be a *kvater(in)* if the physical layout of the location of the *brit* allows her to do without *tzniut* issues.**

The [Rema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) in Shulchan Aruch [YD 265:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.265.11?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) describes how a woman cannot be a *sandak* because of *pritzut* (licentiousness) therefore she is the *kvater(in)* and helps her husband by bringing the baby to the entrance of the synagogue and her husband takes the baby from her to be the *sandak*.

So we see that it is because of *tzniut* (modesty) that a woman wouldn't bring the baby to the *sandak*. The same issue would likely occur nowadays when the *brit* is performed in the men's section of a synagogue. However it would be different in a hall or home separated in two sections, with the *mohel* in the middle, where the woman could come to the *sandak* directly without being in the middle of a crowded assembly of men.

(Note that, in communities where the father is the *sandak*, there are issues of his wife being *nidda* and not being able to touch or pass objects to her husband, which is why she might require another couple to be intermediaries.)

I discussed the above with R Binyamin Tabady who concurs but, of course, one should [consult the local rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734) to ensure he is comfortable with the proceedings.